# Android with two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am working with two fragments in android honeycomb (tab). In the left is listview and in the right is preview of item selected from list, it is button gridview. please help and share the simple code. thanks

Comment: Did you at least try to do something? Whatever, take a look at the iosched app code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this wonderful series of tutorials by tutsplus.

[Working with fragments](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the Honeypad tutorial, it uses Fragments with a ListFragment on the left and a Details Fragment on the right.

http://android-codelabs.appspot.com/resources/tutorials/honeypad/index.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. it's very useful for me... to: Rajdeep Dua, i have already implemented the example that you gave, but any another examples? in this case in the right side is button gridview.many thanks :-)